# Temporary disable jQuery event

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-hover

I have something like this and it has been created from jQuery `.append(html)`

```
 <div class="pPost">
<p>id</p>
<div class="pPostIn">
    <div class="link">
        <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="id"></div>
    <div class="txt"></div>
</div>
```

Then a jQuery function like this:

EDIT: 3

```
$(function () {
$(".link").live({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 0"); //this works
        $(".pPost").die();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css("background-position", ""); //this works
        $(".pPost").live("click", ajaxCall);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

And this works as expected, but the problem I am trying to solve is how to make that `.link` anchor executable as the `.pPost` live function "took 1st place"? I tried to `.unbind()`/`.undelegate()` `.pPost` but I was unsuccessful:

EDIT: 3

```
var ajaxLoad = function () {
    $(".pPost").live("click", function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "rucno/php/archive_page_helper.php",
            data: idData,
            cache: false,

            success: function (html) {                    
                $(pPost).append(html).hide().slideDown(400, function () {
                    $(".link").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
                });
            }
        });            
    });
  return false;
};
```

EDITED once again, but still the same, it wont work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved as "RamboNo5" suggest in post [jQuery - How can I temporarily disable the onclick event listener after the event has been fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921855/jquery-how-can-i-temporarily-disable-the-onclick-event-listener-after-the-even)

I had just to modify it, this is how it's works

html

```
 <div class="pPost">
<p>id</p>
<div class="pPostIn">
    <div class="link">
        <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="id"></div>
    <div class="txt"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
var active= true;
$(function () {
    $(".link").live({
        mouseenter: function () {               
            active= false;                
        },
        mouseleave: function () {                
            active= true;              
        }
    });
    //return false;
});


$(function () {

    $(".pPost").live("click", function () {

        if (!active) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "rucno/php/archive_page_helper.php",
            data: idData,
            cache: false,

            success: function (html) {                           
                $(pPost).append(html).hide().slideDown(400, function () {
                    $(".link").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);                        

                });

            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `live` to bind an event, use `die` to unbind it.
You can't rebind an event just by saying `.bind()` again.

See this question to temporalily unbind an event:
[jquery temporary unbinding events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408082/jquery-temporary-unbinding-events)

**EDIT**

```
var ajaxLoad = function () {
  $.ajax({
    //blablabla
  });
  return false;
};
```

**EDIT**
Rebind ajax loading.

```
// Rebind like this
$(".pPost").live("click", ajaxLoad);
```

**EDIT**
As links are inside `.pPost`, when it's reloaded, links loose their bind and should also be rebinded.

```
// Rebind links
$('a').click(fn);
$('.pPost').load('blabla.html',function() {
    $('.pPost a').click(fn);
});
```

**EDIT**
Be careful with embeded ajax calls:

```
var ajaxLoad = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "blabla.php",
        data: idData,
        cache: false,

        success: function (html) {

            $(pPost).append(html).hide().slideDown(400, function () {
                $(".link").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

And then:

```
$(".pPost").live("click", ajaxCall);
```

Comment: die works dut redbind do not :)
... I added code to the first post

Comment: No rebind doesn't work, really go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408082/jquery-temporary-unbinding-events and read the best answer ! Does your ajax call need to run several times, if not bind `.pPost` with `.once()`.

Comment: yep it has to run again after mouse leave the .link area

Comment: Sorry, maybe you should make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then we could see what's going wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7501/discussion-between-intry-and-sinsedrix)